# Simple RestSharp Post, keepts failing

Tags: restsharp

I have the following snippet, that keeps failing on me:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;

var client = new RestClient("https://api.mydomain.com:443");    
var request = new RestRequest("/Save?api_key=myKeyHere", Method.POST);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;

    if (response.ErrorException != null) {
        Response.Write(response.ErrorException);
    }
```

I get this exception, with the above code:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at RestSharp.Http.WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest webRequest) at RestSharp.Http.PostPutInternal(String method) at RestSharp.Http.AsPost(String httpMethod) at RestSharp.RestClient.DoExecuteAsPost(IHttp http, String method) at RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(IRestRequest request, String httpMethod, Func`3 getResponse)
```

Trying the same URL in cUrl or in Postman (Chrome API tester), it works. So the endpoint works as expected.

But if i change the API to a public dummy test api, i get no error, and i goes through.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 11):

The fix was to use this instead:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: This worked for me.... Can't really explain why though...

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was targeting .NET 4.0 because the app I was adding RestSharp to was older. I switched to .NET 4.7 and everything went through fine.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/restApi");
var request = new RestRequest("/api/v1/FL/Tokens", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);

request.AddJsonBody(fooBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BarResult>(response.Content);
```